# Converting SQL query to Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM adm_species t
JOIN adm_breeds e ON e.species_id = t.id
JOIN fd_registrations s ON s.breeds_id = e.id
WHERE t.code = 'cat'
AND s.sex_id = '2'
AND s.ownername LIKE '%sha%'
```

How do I convert this to Codeigniter Active Record?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('adm_species t');
$this->db->join('adm_breeds e', 'e.species_id = t.id');
$this->db->join('fd_registrations s', 's.breeds_id = e.id');
$this->db->where('t.code', 'cat');
$this->db->where('s.sex_id', 2);
$this->db->like('s.ownername', 'sha', 'both'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

### [Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)