# SQL Query to Codeigniter

Tags: mysql

I am learning Codeigniter and I am trying to convert this SQL query to codeigniter.

```
$query = $this->db->query('select * from carrier_master cm where cm.id IN (select DISTINCT pcp.carrier_id from product_carrier_pricing pcp where pcp.product_id IN (select  DISTINCT p.id from product_master p where p.brand_id ='.$brandId.'))');
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Post your attempt here with your question. Also, this is the first result in Google for "convert sql query to codeigniter": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569055/converting-sql-query-to-codeigniter-active-record

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting SQL query to Codeigniter Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569055/converting-sql-query-to-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: I am new to Stackover flow. How does this work. I know normal logic on how to convert sql query to codeigniter. I just can't figure this specific query.

Comment: Understood. I would suggest altering the language of your question/description to reflect the particular difficulty you are encountering when converting this SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('cm.*');
$this->db->from('carrier_master as cm');
$this->db->join('product_carrier_pricing pcp', 'pcp.carrier_id = cm.id', 
'LEFT');
$this->db->join('product_master p', 'p.id = pcp.product_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('product_category_link pcl', 'pcl.product_id = 
pcp.product_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->where('p.brand_id',$brandId);
$this->db->where('pcl.cat_id',$catId);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I managed to do it. Thank you guys for the help.